Prefix local branch name with name of remote when checking out remote branch
I regularly work in situations where I have multiple remotes for a single project, each of which have their own dev branch. When I check out one of those branches, my local branch gets named dev, but if I already have a dev branch (from a different remote), the checkout fails.
I know I can get around this by renaming my local branch to origin-a/dev or something like that, but is there a way to automatically prefix my local branch with the remote name when checking out a remote branch? This could be a git config setting, a VSCode setting (since I use the built in SCM module to interact with git), or some other setting (maybe a VSCode extension or something?)

The error seems unrelated to your question. You ran the command in the wrong working directory, that's all.

@mkrieger1 Ah, yup, that's embarrassing! Out of curiosity, why did you remove the vscode tag from this? I'm explicitly asking about a workflow in VSCode and whether it's supported in the built-in SCM functionality. I guess I didn't explicitly say that in the question...

Your question didn't say anything about VS Code so far.
